# Display alert when user input is less than specified value.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to display alert box when value inserted by user is less than specified value.and this specified value is taken  from database. I am new in php so that i m not getting whats wrong with this code.

```
         <?php
         $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
          if (!$con)
          {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }

        mysql_select_db("gunjanbid", $con);
        $username=$_SESSION['userName'];
        $id=$_SESSION['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bids WHERE id =$id");
         //$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bid 
       $numrow = mysql_num_rows($result);


        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
       ]
    $bidfee=$row[5];

    }
     ?>




   <?php 
   echo '<script  type="text/javascript">';
    echo  "function validateForm1()";
    {

    echo "var c=document.forms['auction1']['fir'].value";
     echo "var d=document.forms['auction1']['bidamount'].value";

     if echo "( c==null || c=="" )";
         {
    echo   "alert('UserName  must be filled out')";
    echo  "return false";
     }
     echo  "else";
       {
        echo  "if(c<$bidfee)"
        {
      echo  "alert('Bid can not be less than Bid fee')";
       echo  "return false";
        }
       }
          echo  "if (d==null || d=="")";
      {
     echo  "alert('UserName  must be filled out')";
     echo  "return false";
        }
       echo  "else";
       {
      echo "if(d<$bidfee)";
     {
    echo  "alert('Bid can not be less than Bid fee')";
      echo  "return false";
       }
       }
         }
       echo  "</script>";
        ?>
  <form action="multiplebid.php" name="auction1"  onsubmit="return validateForm1()"   method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="" >
<input type="hidden" name="closing_date" value="" >
<input  type="text"  name="fir" value=""  size="5" >              
     <input  type="text" name="sec" value="" size="5" ></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input   type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Bid Now" ></form>
```

The above code is not displaying alert box and showing error that syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting '(' in C:\wamp\www\old\detailproduct.php on line 426
 or if there be any another way to display alert box then plz help me.

Comment: `if echo "( c==null || c=="" )";
         {` that's un invalid syntax, it should be `echo "if ( c==null...` however, it's bad design embedding the js this way. Close your PHP tags and place JS the normal way, without echo/print

Comment: `if echo "( c==null || c=="" )";` syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("gunjanbid", $con);
$username=$_SESSION['userName'];
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bids WHERE id =$id");
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $bidfee=$row[5];
}
?>
<script  type="text/javascript">
var bidfee  =   '<?php echo $bidfee;?>';
function validateForm1(){
    var c=document.forms['auction1']['fir'].value;
    var d=document.forms['auction1']['bidamount'].value;
    if ( c==null || c=="" ){
        alert('UserName  must be filled out');
        return false;
    }else{
        if(c<bidfee){
            alert('Bid can not be less than Bid fee');
                return false;
        }
    }
    if (d==null || d==""){
        alert('UserName  must be filled out');
        return false; 
    }else{
        if(d<bidfee){
            alert('Bid can not be less than Bid fee');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<form action="multiplebid.php" name="auction1"  onsubmit="return validateForm1()"   method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="" >
<input type="hidden" name="closing_date" value="" >
<input  type="text"  name="fir" value=""  size="5" >              
<input  type="text" name="bidamount" value="" size="5" ></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input   type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Bid Now" >
</form>
```

Comment: but problem is it not displaying alert box

Comment: alert box is displaing but when i m inserting more than bidfee it shows alert box that bid can not be less than bid fee.

Comment: first time enter correctly but second time after refresh it does not display alert box when value is less than bidfee

Comment: some time this take value or some time this is not taking any value.